# ¿Por qué se usa el género femenino en estos casos?

Tags: género

En la frase "Nueva York," ¿por qué es el adjetivo "nuevo" declinado al género femenino? Pensaba que el masculino era el género predeterminado. Entonces por qué es el género femenino usado? Similarmente, en "Nueva Jersey," "nueva" es femenino. ¿Se relaciona la razón a la palabra "nuevo" o al sustantivo modificado?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Me parece que el género del adjetivo solamente depende en tipo de lugar del nombre modificado. Por ejemplo, "Nueva Jersey" sí es *un* estado, pero "Jersey" por sí solo es *una* isla. Así, no es importante el estatus de "Nueva Jersey" porque el género del adjetivo depende en el nombre, no la frase. Similarmente, "York" es *una* ciudad. Y es "Nuevo Hampshire" porque "Hampshire" es *un* condado.

Answer (score 6):

York es **una** ciudad, por tanto debe ir en femenino. Piensa como si fuera "Nueva ciudad de York"

Comment: Alguien ya me dio una respuesta como ésta. "Nueva Jersey" es *un* estado, y el artículo aún es femenino.

Comment: Igual que Nueva York, que también es un estado. Supongo que la ciudad existió antes que el estado y heredó el nombre de su ciudad principal

Answer (score 3):

No hay ninguna razón. Si el topónimo es una palabra castellana o de género determinado, el adjetivo suele adecuarse a ella. Por ejemplo “Nuevo Laredo”, “Nuevo México”, o “Nueva Granada”.

Pero cuando se trata de topónimos extranjeros, es simplemente al azar. Por ejemplo, tenemos “Nuevo Brunswick” en “Nueva Jersey”, pero no hay razón para que no sea al revés, excepto que las formas actuales están fijadas por el uso.

Comment: Además, Nuevo Méjico era Nueva Méjico por venir de la provincia mejicana, luego tras alejarse de este origin provinciano, se convirtió en masculino por influencia del nombre *Méjico*).  Como evidencia de ello, tenemos el libro *La historia de la Nueva Méjico* por el capitán Gaspar de Villagra, escrito en el siglo XVII.